# USB stick does not boot on laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, usb, boot, acer-aspire

I just created a bootable usb stick with a linux distro (Trinitry rescue kit), in order to get rid of viruses on a windows 7 laptop, an acer 1410. The stick boots other laptops and desktops but not this one, what could be the reason? Obviously I changed the boot setup in the bios.

Comment: We need more details.  Does the stick show up in the POST drive list?  Are you given the option to boot from it?  Do any error messages pop up, or is it simply "ignored" and the normal boot sequence continued?

Comment: yes, the stick shows up in the POST list, and I can select it during boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a lot of things that causes this problem

- Certain (old) laptops might not support booting from USB stick
- Certain laptop BIOSes have a setting to disable booting from specific devices, or to exclude certain devices from the boot order
- Maybe you need to turn on (or off) the USB legacy function in your BIOS
- Maybe the BIOS won't recognize the USB stick the first time. Try booting from your USB stick, and when it fails, use CTRL+ALT+DELETE (not the power button) to reboot the laptop.
- You can try (at your own risk) to update the laptop's BIOS. Maybe the version you have has a bug, and you can fix it by updating the BIOS